# Passing data to a json/php web-service

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am trying to pass some data to a web-service using JQuery. Here is a simple client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "webservices/gammeList.php?lang=fr",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
    });

    function onError(result) {
        alert("error");
    }

    function onSuccess(result){
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
</script>
```

And a simple server:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['lang']) && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    } else {
        $lang = "en";
    }

    echo (json_encode($lang));
?>
```

It is working properly, but I would like to pass the data using the data setting that way:

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "webservices/gammeList.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {lang: "fr"},
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
});
```

I always get ***"en"*** as a response from the web-service. So here, should I use the same method `$_GET['lang']` to access the input data? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I changed `$_GET['lang']` in `$_POST['lang']` but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: I am confused.
If I use `$_REQUEST['lang']` it works fine. But with `$_POST['lang']` still the same behavior..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing `$_GET['lang']` in `$_POST['lang']`, it was still not working. I deleted the following line:

`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

using then the default value `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use server side $_REQUEST which will work for both POST and GET method:

```
$_REQUEST['lang']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$_GET["Key"]` which is incorrect as you are passing data in POST variables.

You can use either `$_REQUEST["key"]`

```
$lang = $_REQUEST["lang"];
```

or `$_POST["key"]`

```
$lang = $_POST["lang"];
```

to retrieve the data sent to the PHP script.

To read a little bit more about these refer links given below.

[$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)
[$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Answer (score 0):

So then use server side `$_POST`, not `$_GET`:

```
$_POST['lang']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `array` to `json_encode function` like,

```
<?php
    // Also you are using post method in ajax so use $_POST or $_REQUEST here
    if (isset($_REQUEST['lang']) && !empty($_REQUEST['lang'])) {
        $lang = $_REQUEST['lang'];
    } else {
        $lang = "en";
    }

    echo (json_encode(array($lang)));// here passing array to json_encode
?>
```